# GWT - debugging asynchron method call

Tags: java, debugging, gwt

I want to debugg a server side method that is called over my AsyncService from my GWT application. The method is in the interface. I call it in my EntryPoint calss like that:

```
service.loadData(file, new AsyncCallback<Void>() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        System.out.println("loadData - failure");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
        System.out.println("loadData - success");
    }
});
```

My problem is, that the debugger just jumps over the method. It isn't going into the implementation class of my interface.
Is it possible to debug inside this function in the server package?

Comment: Put a break point inside server side method. it should work.

Comment: Yes you can debug server side code also. Put a break point at the beginning of the `ServiceImpl#loadData()` method.

Comment: @Braj I already tried it that way. But the debugger doesn't stop at my break point. It only stops if i make a break point inside the EntryPoint class.

Comment: Make sure you have placed a debug point at the correct class and method. Put a SOP in the beginning of the method and re-run your application in debug mode. Check the console output first.

Comment: @Braj It's at the correct class and method: http://www7.pic-upload.de/19.04.14/cbt2j3crntr3.png  - what is a SOP?

Comment: `System.out.println("Inside my loadData() method");`

Comment: @Braj added - no output. only output is "loadData - success"

Comment: Your server side classes are not in sync. Its not in compiled state. please clean the project. Make sure you have updated server side classes by inspecting its timestamp.

Comment: @Braj Do you mean Project -> Clean...? I've tried that - still no output and no break. I've restarted eclipse and tomcat. What did you mean with the second sentence? Can you explain more detailed what i should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out. It semms that tomcat doesn't support server sided debugging. I tried it with the Google AppEngine and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments your server side classes are not considering the changes.

Please try  it again after removing all the generated stub and re-compiling the project again. I have highlighted all the stubs that needs to be deleted as shown in below snapshot.

[image]

---

-- EDIT --

Try to inspect the RPC calls using Firefox Firebug plugin as shown below :

[image]

Comment: I deleted every thing you said, did a GWT Compile and started the application in debug mode. Stil no output and the application doesn't break.

Comment: Please post a complete code. service, async service, service impl and entry point class.

Comment: ok. I'll do that later. I don't have any time now. Would be nice if you take a look then. thanks

Comment: OK let me try to find the cause. Will update you soon.

Comment: Try to inspect the RPC calls using Firefox Firebug plugin.